# Javascript Chome extension does not load https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js script

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-signin

This is the error that I get when trying to set the google signin button:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com".
```

This is my html header:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="898781594724-s0fh16gcroad2e37ds2q09r5qmoqpu73.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<!-- css file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styleVidyo.css" />
<!-- javascript files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vidyoChromeExt.js"></script>
<!-- Developer code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Google analytics code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<!-- Opensource code -->
</head>
```

This is the manifest:

```
{
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",

"manifest_version": 3,
"omnibox": { "keyword" : "Send a Vidyo Invite" },
"name": "Send a Vidyo Invite",
"description": "Quickly send a Vidyo invite using Google Mail or Google Calendar",
"version": "2.0.2",
"icons": {
 "16": "img/icon_16.png" ,
 "48": "img/icon_48.png" ,
 "128": "img/icon_128.png"
},
 "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://mail.google.com/*", "*://accounts.google.com/*", "*://www.google.com/calendar/*", "*://calendar.google.com/*"],
    "js": ["js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js", "js/vidyoCalendar.js", "js/dateFormat.js"],
    "css": ["css/ui.css"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
"homepage_url": "http://www.vidyo.com",
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
"permissions": [  
    "cookies", 
    "tabs",  
    "*://*.google.com/*", 
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*",
    "notifications",
    "contentSettings",
    "identity"
],  
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js",
    "js/vidyoChromeExt.js",     
    "vidyoChromeExt.html",
    "js/jquery-2.0.3.min.map",
    "img/icon_48.png",
    "img/icon_16.png"
],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["js/eventPage.js"]
},
 "browser_action": {
"default_title": "Send a Vidyo Invite",
"default_icon": "img/icon_128.png",
"default_popup": "vidyoChromeExt.html"
}   
}
```

PS: I edited the content_security_policy line:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js; object-src 'self'",
```

And now I get this error:

```
platform.js:7 Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.5Qa4K6bqWYU.O/m…sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCNyN716KFiep1ch6_hoUSsIDwsHUA/cb=gapi.loaded_0' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js".
```

PPS: I did manage to make it load the scripts, and go past the content_security_policy. but now I get this error:

```
cb=gapi.loaded_0:155 Uncaught gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy
```

Any ideeas? Is this cause it's a extension?
I found this that might help: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/64
But so far. nothing works

Answer (score 0):

I quote:

> .. because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: `"script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com"`

And from your manifest:

```
"content_security_policy":
  "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
```

That doesn't match the `https://apis.google.com` origin, and therefore does exactly [what CSP is supposed to do](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/): refuse to execute.

Read up on [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) in Chrome Extensions, and modify the CSP to allow that **origin**, not individual scripts (as Google API loads more scripts as modules, and you don't know the URLs in advance).

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: Am checking now to see how I can make it allow all the scripts that are loaded from apis.google.com/js/platform.js

Comment: I did manage to make it work. but now I get an error like this:
cb=gapi.loaded_0:155 Uncaught gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy

Comment: is this cause it is an extension?

Comment: Probably. Getting GAPI work in an extension is hard. You way want to look into `chrome.identity` instead.